# How to better do a implicit conversion (cast) for a join?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a strange query like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN #TEMP an ON  an.Id = T1.AccNum
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
                        ON  CAST(T2.Ref_tranID as bigint)= T1.Table1ID
                        AND CAST(T2.Ref_TranLineID as int) = T1.ItmSeq
                        AND T2.PrID = 50
                    where T2.Table2ID IS NULL AND T1.CalDateDate >= '2022-06-15'  and  T1.CalDateDate <= '2022-06-16'
```

one of the issues is that `T1.AccNum` is MAX so I can't use it in a index (this will be fixed this month hehe).

but I think the issue here is these casts.

they are originally varchar. I get some keyLokups that I'm fixing already but, is there a smarter way to deal with those casts?

to be honest we have 2 of these queries (identical) with a union in the middle, but fixing one will fix another.

I tried to populate a temp table with the correct data types but still I got the query running for more than 3 minutes.

Comment: "Better" in what sense? Though I'm afraid implicit casts are never "better"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

- Fix the data types in the base table, and index them
- Create computed columns on the base table, and index them
- Dump some filtered result into a #temp table with the columns converted to the correct data type, and index them
- Induce [batch mode](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/batch-mode-on-row-store-vs-batch-mode-tricks/) if you're on [Enterprise Edition](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/how-useful-is-column-store-in-standard-edition/)

There's no good, or better, way to do this at runtime.